# Spam links in an already upvoted answer of a locked question

Tags: support, hyperlinks, spam

[An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5350026) to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731233/activemq-or-rabbitmq-or-zeromq-or), which is locked as historically significant, has a link pointing to a completely unrelated site about drugs:

```
Docu: http://nubyonrails.com/articles/about-this-blog-beanstalk-messaging-
```

Notice how it says "nuby" instead of "ruby". Might be an honest typo (domain name that someone eventually squatted).

Should we fix it?

Comment: http://rubyonrails.com/ doesn't seems to respond neither. Maybe https://github.com/beanstalkd/beanstalkd could be a valid target, but it's light.

Comment: Only author of post can answer this, even rubyonrails.com doesn't even exist. official rails framework website is https://rubyonrails.org/ this link is mentioned here as well https://www.tienle.com/2013/07-04/beanstalk-messaging-queue.html

Comment: Link is dead anyway. Moderator should remove it.

Comment: This is the sort of thing you should bring up on the [per site Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Are you looking for this specific question to be fixed, or advise on what to do in this type of situation anywhere on the Stack Exchange Network? Currently, you question reads as you wanting this specific question fixed.

Comment: @Makyen I just wanted to point out the fact, that there is an answer (and a highly ranked in search engines too) like that. Isn't this, or rather the SO Meta the place I should be doing it in?

Comment: SO Meta is the place for something which is specific to SO ("please fix this post"). Here, SE Meta, is the appropriate place for questions which affect the whole network. With respect to topicality, there's a special case for system bugs, which can be reported on any Meta site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not seem to be spam to me.

At the time the answer was posted [the page existed](https://web.archive.org/web/20110223225951/http://nubyonrails.com/articles/about-this-blog-beanstalk-messaging-queue) and was providing the information promised.

Still, as others have said, the link is dead now, so either remove it, or link the archived version.